# Change body max height

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to change `max-height` of `body` to `height` of section?
I was thinking of things like that but they seem to not be working...

```
document.body.style.max-height = document.getElementById('my-section');
```

(I have a few sections)

Comment: `document.body.style.maxHeight = document.getElementById('my-section').style.maxHeight;` in JS css properties are camelCase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The property is called `style.maxHeight` not `style.max-height`, JS uses camelCase instead of dashes, means your code will look like this:

```js
document.body.style.maxHeight = document.getElementById('my-section').style.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

On the right-side of the assignment you see that I reference `height` of the element as a Javascript object member. On the left side you can see that I refer it via its name, but square brackets and quotes are wrapped around it:

```
document.body.style["max-height"] = document.getElementById('my-section').style.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change max-height to maxHeight
If you have properties with - divider, you need to use camelCase name of property.